# List of lists view in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Let's say I have blogs and comments in my CouchDB. Every comment references the blog id. How would I create a view that returns the list of all blogs with comments included? E.g.:

```
[{"blog_title": "a", "comments": ["hi"]},
 {"blog_title": "b", "comments": ["hi"]}]
```

A workaround would be a view that returns a list including both all blogs an all comments. The client would then need to do the processing manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "Approach #2: Comments Separate" at http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins
Also see "Using the Power of View Collation" in the same page.